Pipeline for ML model using LabelEncoding in a Transformer
I'm attempting to incorporate various transformations into a scikit-learn pipeline along with a LightGBM model. This model aims to predict the prices of second-hand vehicles. Once trained, I plan to integrate this model into an HTML page for practical use.
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
import joblib

print(numeric_features)
`['car_year', 'km', 'horse_power', 'cyl_capacity']`
print(categorical_features)
`['make', 'model', 'trimlevel', 'fueltype', 'transmission', 'bodytype', 'color']`

# Define transformers for numeric and categorical features
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', StandardScaler())])
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('labelencoder', LabelEncoder())])

# Combine transformers using ColumnTransformer
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)
    ]
)

# Append the LightGBM model to the preprocessing pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
    ('model', best_lgb_model)
])

# Fit the pipeline to training data
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

The output I get when training is:
LabelEncoder.fit_transform() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

I recomnend use only 1 pipeline not 3 and for categorical use onehotencoding, labelencoder is more useful for labels

OrdinalEncoder does something very similar to LabelEncoder but is meant for independent variables.

@KuLeMi, would it make sense to use OneHotEncoding for categorical variables, even in cases where there are columns with up to 100 different values?

@BenReiniger in my case, variables are mostly dependent

@alexquilis1 independent variables = explanatory variables = features = X and dependent variable = target variable = y

@alexquilis1 LabelEncoder may only be used for encoding the target, see docu for LabelEncoder: "This transformer should be used to encode target values, i.e. y, and not the input X"

@alexquilis1 With LightGBM, there is no need to encode categorical variables, you can simply keep them as categorical, LightGBM can handle categorical features
